# SQL query for partial match with popup

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I`m trying to create a search query in MS ACCESS with SQL for a popup. What I have right now is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM InventoryArchive
WHERE DocumentID LIKE [Document ID];
```

This works well, it pops a popup, asking me to enter my document ID, but only allows exact matches. Can I somehow change this, so that if there is a partial match (say, I write 1, and it returns 1, 10, 11 , 12 as well), it will return those as well? I can`t seem to find a workaround for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My guess for access would be something like `SELECT *
FROM InventoryArchive
WHERE DocumentID LIKE '*' & [Document ID] & '*'`.

Comment: @HansUp That didn`t work, I tried.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Perfect, that works. Thank you very much! If you write it as an answer, I`ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating your search string with a leading and trailing `*` will match the search string anywhere inside the field;

```
SELECT * 
FROM InventoryArchive 
WHERE DocumentID LIKE '*' & [Document ID] & '*'
```